# Ascending Order Textbox Separated with Comma

Tags: vb.net

I'm new here. I have a textbox,
Textbox1.text = 1,2,7,4,11.
I want to be Output:
1,2,4,7,11.

```
Textbox1.text = 1,2,7,4,11.
I want to be Output:
1,2,4,7,11.
```

VB.Net

I found this code and it works for who wants it.

Code:

```
Private Sub Array()
    Dim InputNumbers, SplitInputNumbers, ArrayCount, ReSort, iterInputNum, Num1, Num2
    InputNumbers = OutputText1.Text
    SplitInputNumbers = Split(InputNumbers, ",")
    ArrayCount = UBound(SplitInputNumbers)
    ReSort = "YES"
    While ReSort = "YES"
        ReSort = "NO"
        For iterInputNum = 0 To ArrayCount
            If iterInputNum < ArrayCount Then
                If CInt(SplitInputNumbers(iterInputNum)) > CInt(SplitInputNumbers(iterInputNum + 1)) Then
                    Num1 = SplitInputNumbers(iterInputNum)
                    Num2 = SplitInputNumbers(iterInputNum + 1)
                    SplitInputNumbers(iterInputNum + 1) = Num1
                    SplitInputNumbers(iterInputNum) = Num2
                    ReSort = "YES"
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End While
    Dim iterSortedNum, SortedNumericArray
    For iterSortedNum = 0 To ArrayCount
        If iterSortedNum = 0 Then
            SortedNumericArray = SplitInputNumbers(iterSortedNum)
        Else
            SortedNumericArray = SortedNumericArray & "," & SplitInputNumbers(iterSortedNum)
        End If
    Next
    OutputText1.Text = (SortedNumericArray)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this. It takes your string splits it into an array. Converts each substring into a number, Making a new Integer array. Sorts that new array. and then using join converts it back into a comma separated string

```
Dim str = "1,2,7,4,11"
Dim b = String.Join(",", str.Split(",").Select(Function(x) Integer.Parse(x.Trim())).OrderBy(Function(x) x))
```